# Avoid showing tab anchor tag title attribute as tool tip

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

jQuery 1.7.1 - I'm using jQuery tabs widget in my JSP and have the following code to represent tabs,

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="t1" title="content">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="t2" title="content">Polls</a></li>
        <li><a href="t3" title="content">Events</a></li>
    </ul>
        <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

These 3 tabs appear OK in the browser, but when I mouse over the tabs 'content' is getting displayed as a tool tip in Chrome, Firefox and IE. Any way to avoid seeing 'content' as tool tip and provide the actual tool tip like 'Click to see Gallery' etc.

EDIT: I use title attribute to specify the container for loading ajax content,
 http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode

Comment: The `title` tags describes what will be viewed as a tooltip by the browser. Set `title` to the tooltip you want to display. It doesn't have to be 'content'.

Comment: hey, does setting the title tag really works? It didn't work with mine, it still create a new `<div>` right under the `<ul>`. So, since your `<div>` is already under the `<ul>`, maybe you can just remove the title tag.

Comment: Okay, I'll answer with some suggestions.

Comment: Phelios - I got some styles attached to that div (content), so i need it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely have to have the `title` attribute then you could try removing it temporarily on `mouseover`.

```
var temptitle;
$('a').hover( 
   function() {
      // remove the title
      temptitle = $(this).attr('title')
      $(this).attr('title','')
   },
   function() {
      // replace the title
      $(this).attr('title',temptitle)
   }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$('a[title]').hover( 
   function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
   }, 
   function() { } 
);
```

Comment: sorry, just tried it out on jsfiddle...and it doesn't work :( ...I actually thought it would be able to get rid of the default browser behavior, but apparently not...

Comment: This should be possible, annoying that it isn't.